# Interface with default methods vs abstract class, and what's the motivation?

Tags: java, c#

**Context**

I've recently came across this C# proposal [default interface methods](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md)
I've read both the specification and **more importantly the motivation**. Possibly I missed something, but the motivation is a bit stinks me.

The only practical difference between interface and a fully abstract class **was** that a future class can implement (so be [IS A]) multiple interfaces, but can inherit (so be [IS A]) from only one abstract class,  (and all the consequences)

What is not clear for me what is the exact difference between abstract classes and interfaces with default methods **now**, ***except*** that we can bring multiple (implementation) inheritance into the picture with default methods, which is not possible with abstract classes. (I do not want open the question/discussion is it good or bad, this is not the topic here)

However the motivation talks about completely different, three points:

- *"...API author to add methods to an interface in future versions without breaking source..."*. Well an "API" author can add methods to an abstract class also in a future version *if he implements them* without breaking anything.
- *"...enables C# to interoperate with APIs targeting Android (Java) and iOS (Swift),..."*. I think **a language design decision, especially about abstractions and OOP patterns like multiple inheritance is a bit higher level** than interoperate with Swift. I also think, this is only the 0.0x percent of interoperation issues, and also can be solved with other ways.
- *"...As it turns out, adding default interface implementations provides the elements of the "traits" language feature..."*. This is a very shallow statement, especially it refers to wikipedia "traits". By definition, traits allow adding methods *without* multiple inheritance (having [IS A] relationship with a super). However interfaces definitely are about [IS A]... Not talking about the fact, that traits are at least arguable good practice

**Question**

My question is what is the real difference (or motivation), or what am I missing?

Comment: Re: the first bullet. Don't think about abstract classes for a moment. Just think about interfaces. You've released v1 of your project, many people have implemented the interface, now you want to add a convenience method to the interface. That's the scenario, nothing to do with abstract classes. The fact that *you* don't find the motivations particularly convincing doesn't mean that there must be some *other* motivation.

Comment: Thanks, good point, actually this worth an answer  I think.

Comment: extension methods are another way you can add a "convenience method" for an interface. Because an interface is not allowed to maintain state the addition of an  extension method would allow you to achieve the same thing. I personally thing they have muddied the waters with this change

Answer (score 2):

They add this feature in Java 8. So you can add the `Java` tag and ask to Java developers what they can do with it. It also exists on `Haskell` and `Scala` apparently.

### Multi-Inheritance

What come to my mind first is Multi-Inheritance. As a class can implement multiple interfaces, you can for example to solve the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

In Java this is how they do:

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    public default void foo() {
        System.out.println("A -> foo()");
    }
}

public interface InterfaceB {
    public default void foo() {
        System.out.println("B -> foo()");
    }
}

private class Test implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
    // Compilation error : "class Test inherits unrelated defaults for foo() from types InterfaceA and InterfaceB"
}
```

So you have to either implement the methods (which override the default implementations) or call one of the `super`:

```
public class Test implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
     public void foo() {
        InterfaceB.super.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: While serving a similar purpose, Haskell type classes are not Java/C# interfaces. It's much more like Scala's implicit classes implementing a common trait. When you call a type class method, instance is dispatched statically using the types of arguments. There's proposal for C# to add something like this: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/110

Answer (score 2):

After introducing Default Method, it seems that interfaces and abstract classes are the same. However, they are still a different concept in Java 8.

The abstract class can define constructors. They are more structured and can have a state associated with them. While in contrast, default method can be implemented only in the terms of invoking other interface methods, with no reference to a particular implementation's state. Hence, both are used for different purposes and choosing between two really depends on the scenario context.